# Add Swing objects in Play 2.0 framework

Tags: swing, scala

Good afternoon,

I want to know if it will be possible to add Scala Swing objects (especially JFrame objects) in a Play 2.0 application, I look for something like this but I haven't found nothing.

I need a Text Area that the user can write, and after that when he/she submit,  I need to create an instance of a Scala class which after that it will show in a JFrame are (if I can) something related with the textarea input.

I can do the textarea form with HTML but the other part I don't know how to do it if not with JFrames.

Are many other ways to do this?

The example of what I can do is (it's a App related on Lambda Calculi):

x ---> create a Var elemnt and display it in a JFrame
\x.x ----> create a Abs(Var,Var) element and display it in a JFrame
...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're mixing technilogies. Either you create a standalone desktop app in Swing with JFrames. Then you don't need Play/HTML. Or you create a web application in Play with HTML front-end and you don't use JFrames or any other Swing objects. Please add some background about what you're trying to achieve. Seems werid right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piotr's comment is correct; the two technologies (HTML and Swing) are very separate. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish; however, it sounds like what you want to do is possible via Javascript. A good tutorial for Javascript can be found here: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript. Javascript is also very easy to integrate into a Play project; you can place your Javascript files in your project's `/public` folder and reference them from your HTML files using `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my bad explanation. My Scala class parses the string to a structure and I want/need to represent it. 
I want to represent it like a graph (or something similar) 
So as you say, I need to forget swing and look for a JS library that gives me the same functionality. 
Am I wrong?